# How to render data in cards using ListView?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to render Local json file by listing it in cards, Im using FlatList View but couldn't get it rendered.

Here is my code Snippet :

```
       import React, { Component, View, FlatList } from 'react';
      import { Image } from 'react-native';
      import {
        Container,
        Header,
        Title,
        Content,
        Button,
        Icon,
        Card,
        CardItem,
        Text,
        Thumbnail,
        Left,
        Body,
        Right
      } from 'native-base';


      import styles from './styles';

      const json = require('./fixtures.json');
      const logo = require('../../../assets/logo.png');
      const cardImage = require('../../../assets/cskvsdd.jpg');


      class Fixtures extends Component {
        render() {
          return (

      <FlatList
      renderItem={({item}) => {
            <Container style={styles.container}>
              <Header>
                <Left>
                  <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                    <Icon name="arrow-back" />
                  </Button>
                </Left>
                <Body>
                  <Title>Fixtures</Title>
                </Body>
                <Right />
              </Header>

    <Content padder>
      <Card style={styles.mb}>
        <CardItem>
          <Left>
            <Thumbnail source={logo} />
            <Body>
              <Text>json data</Text>
              <Text note>json data</Text>
            </Body>
          </Left>
        </CardItem>

        <CardItem cardBody>
          <Image
            style={{
              resizeMode: 'cover',
              width: null,
              height: 200,
              flex: 1
            }}
            source={cardImage}
          />
        </CardItem>

        <CardItem style={{ paddingVertical: 0 }}>
          <Left>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon active name="thumbs-up" />
              <Text>josn data</Text>
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon active name="chatbubbles" />
              <Text>json data</Text>
            </Button>
          </Body>
          <Right>
            <Text>json data</Text>
          </Right>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
    </Content>
  </Container>
}
/>
);
}
}

export default Fixtures;
```

I Have overcome many tutorials before asking here. But couldn't figure it out. Apologies if this is too novice.

Kindly help me render json data to cards by refactoring my code.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 3):

By looking at your code snippet I realized that you are not setting the data anywhere in the code. please pass the array of data into Flatlist.

```
<FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
  keyExtractor={(item, index)=> index}
/>
```

`keyExtractor` should be unique .

Comment: pass that data= dataArray
dataArray is your json array  [ {....}, {....}, {....} ] 
in renderItem item represents each elements of your array.

Comment: What you want me to do

Comment: Bro add this at the end of the code export default Fixtures;

Comment: okay i found it because react expects a string we need to convert the key extractor toString().  There are no issues now but the data is not rendered to my screen. Its blank

Comment: Can you check whether you are getting data in `const json = require('./fixtures.json');`  just add a log and check, inside render before return

Comment: That's what you are not getting data... so its empty... can you send me the structure of the file fixtures.json

Comment: But I can access the data. Check whether you have given proper path for `const json = require('./fixtures.json');`

Comment: yeah i did. can you render it as cards?! if so kindly help me with it! im not getting it. also here we cant extend comments. :(

Answer (score 0):

Please check flatlist documentation:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

Make sure your JSON data is correctly formated and accessed.

Comment: Why are you posting your answer twice?

Comment: simple mistake, mate, erased previous answer. The app didn't show any answers when I tried to post mine.

Comment: It's okay, just giving you a notice. And here's another one: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.